# SVG Clip Path applies to first class only

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I'm trying to apply a clip-path to multiple divs, but Safari seems to only be applying the clip path to the first instance. Below is the stripped down code. I also put together a pen that you can find here -> http://codepen.io/hillspro/pen/GjYRAA

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="object"></div>
   <div class="object"></div>
   <div class="object"></div>
   <div class="object"></div>
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
 <defs>
   <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" >
    <polygon points=".5,0 .95,.25 .95,.75 .5,1  .05,.75 .05,.25"/>
   </clipPath>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

INLINE - CSS

```
.object{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:15px;
  background:brown;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  clip-path:url('#clip-shape'); 
  -webkit-clip-path:url('#clip-shape');
}
```

Comment: This looks like a straight up bug in Safari. Tried lots of different ways to poke it, but no alternative seems to work.